# FB api comments notifications

Tags: facebook, notifications, comments, subscribe

I'm working on a classified ads site that works with FB sdk. To upload a classified ad, the user must give permission to the SDK application. After creating a classified ad, fb comments shown below it. What I need is that when someone makes a comment, he gets a notification to ad owner with a link to the site. This is possible?
I hope you can help me, some days ago I'm looking for a solution and I can not find it.

Answer (score 0):

may be the real time updates may help here [facebook real time api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.2). Though i am not able to find the functionality as such.

You can come up with something of the sort.

- At the end of the day or low load times you can traverse all the shared posts for new comments in that day. If there was a comment you can extract that and send that to admin of that ad on his email.